# How to update/change values of BehaviorSubject<object>?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Given a

```
BehaviorSubject<object> smartObject = new BehaviorSubject<object>(
    {key1: value1,
     key2: { key2_1: value2_1, key2_2: value2_2}, 
    ...}
);
```

How can I change each value and how can I add new keys?

Like so:

```
    notsmartObject.key1 = value24; 
    notsmartObject.key2.key2_1 = xy; 
    notsmartObject['newKey'] = newValue;
```

I know of .next(), but I dont want to copy the whole object, add/change whatever I want and put it into the next function. 
Seems a bit inefficient and risky to me, since the current smartObject could be overwritten before .next() can be executed with the new Object. 
This is what I mean:

```
let newObject = smartObject.getValue(); 
newObject.key1 = value24; 
...
smartObject.next(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something like this if that's what you're asking:

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject();

...

subject
  .pipe(
    take(1),
  )
  .subscribe(buffer => subject.next({
    ...buffer,
    foo: 42,
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats the solution. I would also add that foo:42 will always override the current foo on the same level or add it if it isn't there. To change something nested like this: {thefoo:{foo:22}} the part of ...buffer, foo:42 needs to be changed to ...buffer, thefoo:{foo:42}.

Comment: yeah sure, what I did above just overrides that property